# How do you identify InnoDB table corruption?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona-server

I have some tables that are partitioned and have several indexes on a replicated slave. After copying the snap shot (verified safe) to a new slave and upgrading mysqld from 5.1.42 to 5.5.15 and restarting replication, I'm getting InnoDB crashes with the error message "Invalid pointer ..."

These errors have happened across 2 servers with different hardware and O/S. After running:

`ALTER TABLE .... COALESCE PARTION n;`

the problem goes away for that table.

My question is larger in scope, though, and that is "How do you identify InnoDB table corruption?" or rephrased "How do you assess InnoDB table health?" Is **"CHECK TABLE"** the only tool available to identify problems pre-crash?

Not sure if it matters, but the crashes occurred running:
Version: '5.5.15-55-log'  socket: '/opt/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release rel21.0, Revision 158

Comment: Hi Randy!  I think the responses here are credible - InnoDB identified its own corruption.  Maybe you should rephrase your question, why would what you doing cause InnoDB to be corrupt?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Morgan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1268/morgan-tocker) gives a hint in his comment that InnoDB is constantly checking for corrupted pages by doing checksums on the pages it reads. If InnoDB finds a checksum mismatch, it will <strike>crash</strike> stop the server.

If you want to speed that process up (instead of waiting for InnoDB to read the corrupted page), you can use [`innochecksum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innochecksum.html):

> Because checksum mismatches will cause InnoDB to deliberately shut down a running server, it can be preferable to use this tool rather than waiting for a server in production usage to encounter the damaged pages.

An interesting caveat:

> innochecksum cannot be used on tablespace files that the server already has open. For such files, you should use CHECK TABLE to check tables within the tablespace.

So yes, for  an online table `CHECK TABLE` is probably the tool (or as pointed out [in another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/how-do-you-identify-innodb-table-corruption/6219#6219) `mysqlcheck` if you want to do more than a single database at a time.)

If you can shut down your database you can force it the checksums using `innochecksum`

**Anecdotal:**
On a innodb tablespace of 29GB  (with `innodb_file_per_table=1`), this script took about 2 Minutes

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls /var/lib/mysql/*/*.ibd)
do
  innochecksum -v $i
done
```

As a bonus, though, since you are running Percona, they implemented a new method for [fast innodb checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/innodb_fast_checksum.html?id=percona-server:features:innodb_fast_checksum). I've never used it, but it might speed up the process.

Comment: Gonna give it a try here, seems to be the solution @randymelder is looking for +1

Comment: Percona server has some other nice features.  See innodb_corrupt_table_action http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/reliability/innodb_corrupt_table_action.html (!!)

Comment: @DTest : innochecksum is the way to go. This one's a keeper. +1 !!!

Comment: @DTest : Hats off to you today on this one !!!!

Comment: @MorganTocker Interesting. Going to have to get my knowledge vacuum and do some research into percona

Comment: Percona, great surprise of the day to me.

Comment: @DTest You read my question and answered it with probably the best possible answer. Many of my questions are rhetorical in nature as attempt to stimulate discussion and improve the body of knowledge on stack exchange. My intention was to point out that InnoDB has few tools to help out DBAs. I'm really surprised no one mentioned "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" even though it doesn't target a single table.

Comment: Good Bounty Hunting on this one !!!

Answer (score 7):

WARNING: before trying any of these instructions it is strongly recommended to verify that there is a healthy backup of your database in hands, just in case. (thanks to @Nick for the warning)

Try to use the `mysqlcheck` command. On a terminal:

```bsh
mysqlcheck -u username -p --databases database1 database2
```

This command will output a list of all tables and a status telling you if there was some kind of corruption:

```
table1  OK
table2  OK
table3  OK
tableN  OK
```

With that in hands you will already know which tables you have to repair. Just in case you want to repair everything at once:

```bsh
mysqlcheck -u username -p --auto-repair --databases database1 database2
```

More about `mysqlcheck`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Note: you tagged your question with [percona](/questions/tagged/percona). I had no clue of what was that so I googled. It seems to be a fork of MySQL, but I have no reason to believe the commands are incompatible (fingers crossed).

---

Somebody pointed me to this guide that has more specific instructions for InnoDB database recovery for more critical situations where the entire database does not start: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-database-myisam-innodb-1634.html

Comment: mysqlcheck is a synonym for 'check table ...' -1

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: Not true. First, mysqlcheck is a command-line utility and CHECK TABLE is a SQL statement (it's like to compare orange to lemmons).Also, you CAN'T check an entire database with CHECK TABLE without including ALL the table names in the SQL statement (it would not be very productive too)

Comment: And mysqlcheck has an option to --auto-repair the tables that are corrupted while CHECK TABLE only checks if the tables are corrupted or not, but can't make any repair.

Comment: Conclusion: they are definitely not synonym. They might have some intersections, but mysqlcheck can do much more for you in this specific case.

Comment: And to be even more conclusive, the documentation link you sent says: ">mysqlcheck uses the SQL statements CHECK TABLE, REPAIR TABLE, ANALYZE TABLE, and OPTIMIZE TABLE in a convenient way for the user. It determines which statements to use for the operation you want to perform."

Comment: What are the implications of using `--auto-repair`? Is there any chance for data loss?  I would edit these caveats, if any, into your answer so the careless reader is not surprised when they come across your answer and just blindly run the command against their databases.

Comment: Humm, that's an excellent point @Nick. I had to repair databases only in really rare situations and that mysqlcheck command worked like miracle. But I only used it after double check if there was a working backup from the corrupted databases. Better to clarify this. Good point.

Comment: @randymelder - You are wrong to say mysqlcheck is a synonym for `CHECK TABLE`. The documentation you linked to states: "`mysqlcheck` uses the SQL statements `CHECK TABLE`, `REPAIR TABLE`, `ANALYZE TABLE`, and `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in a convenient way for the user. It determines which statements to use for the operation you want to perform, and then sends the statements to the server to be executed." That is not a synonym; that is a user interface to a collection of statements.

Comment: @Nick - Yes, but you are splitting hairs. The question is about InnoDB. Please describe how any of what mysqlcheck does can detect problems in InnoDB tables.

Comment: @randymelder - Err, you asked about detecting corruption, and `mysqlcheck` [finds and fixes corruption](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_auto-repair). For InnoDB, it's true that `mysqlcheck` will be unable to fix the corruption, it can just find it. In that case you'll have to use `mysqldump` and the `mysql` to [export and reload the data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html) (search for "InnoDB" on that page).

Answer (score 7):

According to [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide, Page 443,444 Section 30.4**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127):

> You can check InnoDB tables by using the CHECK TABLE command or using
>   a client program to issue the statement for you. However, if an InnoDB
>   table has problems, you cannot fix it by using REPAIR TABLE because
>   that statement applies only to MyISAM.
>
> If a table check indicates that an InnoDB table has problems, you
>   should be able to restore the table to a consistent state by dumping
>   it with mysqldump, dropping it, and recreating it from that dump.
>
> In the event of a crash of a MySQL Server or on the host on which it
>   runs, some InnoDB tables might need repairs. Normally, it suffices
>   simply to restart the server because the InnoDB storage engine
>   performs auto-recovery as part of its startup sequence. In rare cases,
>   the server might not start up due to the failure of InnoDB
>   auto-recovery. If that happens, use the following procedure:
>
> - Restart the server with the --innodb_force_recovery option set to a
>     value in the rage from 1 to 6. These values indicate increasing levels
>     of caution in a avoiding a crash, and increasing levels of tolerance
>     for possible inconsistency in the recovered tables. A good value to
>     start with is 4.
> - When you start the server with --innodb_force_recovery set to a
>     non-zero value, InnoDB treats the tablespace as read-only.
>     Consequently, you should dump the InnoDB tables with mysqldump and
>     then drop them while the option is in effect. Then restart the server
>     without the --innodb_force_recovery option. When the server comes up,
>     recover the InnoDB tables from the dump files.
> - If the preceding steps fail, it's necessary to restore the InnoDB
>     tables from a previous backup.

Please read MySQL Docs on [**InnoDB Forced Recovery**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Comment: FWIW, the certification guide has a very politically correct answer :)  If you CHECK TABLE on an InnoDB table and it actually is corrupt, it will never return as "corrupt", it will crash the server.  The statement is almost obsolete in InnoDB, because every time you read InnoDB pages it is checking for corruption (via page checksums).

Answer (score 2):

I wonder what happens if anyone uses InnoDB data created via InnoDB Plugin and then switch to another version of InnoDB. That could create possible page corruption in the eyes of mysqld.

Note what the [**MySQL Documentation on InnoDB File Format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-file-format-overview.html) says about this possibility :

> In general, a newer version of InnoDB may create a table or index that
>   cannot safely be read or written with a prior version of InnoDB
>   without risk of crashes, hangs, wrong results or corruptions. The
>   InnoDB Plugin introduces a new mechanism to guard against these
>   conditions, and to help preserve compatibility among database files
>   and versions of InnoDB.

I would scrap the data on the slave. In fact, I would just use brute force by getting a logical dump (mysqldump) of the data:

- Drop all databases using InnoDB on the slave
- Shutdown mysql on the slave
- Delete ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 on the slave
- Start mysql on the slave, letting ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 get recreated
- mysqldump the data from the master into the slave

My original anwser posted is considered 'old school'. Yet, in this case, I would definitely look into the file formats being used by .ibd and/or ibdata1.